# Scala list with same adjacent values

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have this list:

```
List("Black","Black","Green","White")
```

How can I check if a list has two adjacent values which are the same? Like so:

```
List("Black","Black","Green","White") true

List("Black","Yellow","Green","White") false

List("Black","Yellow","Black","Yellow") false
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to Valy Dia's solution, you can also write:

```
list.sliding(2).exists(_.distinct.size == 1)
```

#### REPL Session

```
scala> def check[A](l: Seq[A]): Boolean = l.sliding(2).exists(_.distinct.size == 1)
check: [A](l: Seq[A])Boolean

scala> check("A" :: "B" :: Nil)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> check("A" :: "B" :: "B" ::Nil)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> check("A" :: "B" :: "C":: "B" ::Nil)
res2: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```scala
def check[A](l: List[A]): Boolean = 
 l.zip(l.tail).exists{ case (x,y) => x == y }

check(List("Black","Black","Green","White"))
//res5: Boolean = true

check(List("Black","Yellow","Green","White"))
//res6: Boolean = false

check(List("Black","Yellow","Black","Yellow"))
//res7: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val listA = List("Black","Black","Green","White")

listA.sliding(2).map{case a::b::_ if a == b => true else false}.contains(true)
```

Comment: I don´t think that is what he asked, "two adjacent values"

Comment: updated the question with another example at the end

Comment: Your `case` expression is wrong - `a::b` binds `a` to the head and `b` to the tail so `a == b` is always false since you're comparing a `String` to a `List[String]`. You can replace the `map/contains` with exists i.e. `listA.sliding(2).exists { case a::b::_ => a == b }`.